# Installing Valgrind Patches

Tags: valgrind, patch

I am tying to use Valgrind to tell me stuff about memory usage in my C programs.  I have a very simple program:

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect no memory leaks.  But when I run `Valgrind ./myFile` I get this:

```
Syscall param msg->desc.port.name points to uninitialised byte(s)
```

The trace it prints out doesn't have anything to do with my source code.

I've found sites that refer to a bug and patches to fix it, but I'm wondering: aside from manually typing in the changes to Valgrind's files, how do I get the changes onto my Mac?

Comment: Which versions of Valgrind and macOS are you using?

Comment: Valgrind 13.4.0, MacOS Sierra 10.12.6